# Adding parameters to sqlCommand query

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm doing my first database migration and I'm trying to recreate this `sqlCommand` so that it will add the correct values to the representative objects.

```
    string sqlCommand = "UPDATE WITestData SET " +
            "Width01 = ?, Angle01 = ?, Comment01 = ?, " +
            "Width02 = ?, Angle02 = ?, Comment02 = ?, " +
            "Width03 = ?, Angle03 = ?, Comment03 = ?, " +
            "Width04 = ?, Angle04 = ?, Comment04 = ?, " +
            "Width05 = ?, Angle05 = ?, Comment05 = ?, " +
            "Width06 = ?, Angle06 = ?, Comment06 = ?, " +
            "Width07 = ?, Angle07 = ?, Comment07 = ?, " +
            "Width08 = ?, Angle08 = ?, Comment08 = ?, " +
            "Width09 = ?, Angle09 = ?, Comment09 = ?, " +
            "Width10 = ?, Angle10 = ?, Comment10 = ? " +
            "WHERE ReportNumber = @reportNumber";
        var parameters = new object[31];
        for (int i = 0; i < WITestData.WIData.Length; i++)
        {
            parameters[3 * i] = WITestData.WIData[i].Width;
            parameters[3 * i + 1] = WITestData.WIData[i].Angle;
            parameters[3 * i + 2] = WITestData.WIData[i].Comment;

        }  parameters[30] = WITestData.ReportNumber;
        if (ExecuteNonQuery(sqlCommand, parameterList))
        {
            var index = m_DataManager.Database.WITestData.FindIndex(t => t.ReportNumber == WITestData.ReportNumber);
            m_DataManager.Database.WITestData[index] = WITestData;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I have added the following to the for(...) to assign each object a seperate parameter so it will output the correct values.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < WITestData.WIData.Length; i++)
        {
            //input Parameters into sqlCommand
            string widthParameter = $"@width{counter}";
            string angleParameter = $"@angle{counter}";
            string commentParameter = $"@comment{counter}";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter(widthParameter, WITestData.WIData[i].Width));
                parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@angle", angleParameter));
                parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter("@comment", commentParameter));

                parameterList.Add(command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reportNumber", WITestData.ReportNumber));

                command.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            parameters[3 * i] = WITestData.WIData[i].Width;
            parameters[3 * i + 1] = WITestData.WIData[i].Angle;
            parameters[3 * i + 2] = WITestData.WIData[i].Comment;

            counter++;
        }
```

Note: I've created an `int counter = 1` and a `var parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();` at the top of the method.

How do i input the width/angle/comment parameters into the sqlCommand and make sure that they are correctly assigned with their values?

Comment: You have a command.Paramenters.Clear inside that using. The parameters are gone after that

Comment: @Steve Yes i have because otherwise the parameters would not read correctly, for some reason. I've tried the command.parameters.Clear in other methods and it displays the correct information this way.

Answer (score 0):

First thing wrong is the *command.Parameters.Clear();* in your code. This removes all parameters from the command, however, it seems that after that line you never readd your parameters to the command object but instead you try to add them to your type undefined object array.

Trying to fix you code I start from the basic information present in your code. Your query requires 31 parameters. So, I assume that *WIData.Length* is 10 and a final parameter (the *ReportNumber*) is added after the loop

You can simplify a lot your code with this approach

```
// A command requires an sql text and an OPEN connection to execute....
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlCommand, connection);

// Use directly the parameters collection inside the command object
var parameters = cmd.Parameters;

// Loop over the WIData array length (10 times = 30 parameters)
for (int i = 0; i < WITestData.WIData.Length; i++)
{
    // No need to give an unique name, however, if you really want a name 
    //  you can replace ? with 
    // "W"+i.ToString(), "A"+i.ToString() and "C"+i.ToString()
    parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = WITestData.WIData[i].Width;
    parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = WITestData.WIData[i].Angle;
    parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = WITestData.WIData[i].Comment;
}  
parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = WITestData.ReportNumber;
```

I assume also the datatype of the parameters is Decimal, Strings and integer, you should replace the OleDbType if they are not correct, but don't remove the type. It ensure the correct parsing of your values.

This is the standard approach, but if you want to keep your current code then you could change your loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < WITestData.WIData.Length; i++)
{
    string widthParameter = $"@width{counter}";
    string angleParameter = $"@angle{counter}";
    string commentParameter = $"@comment{counter}";
    parameterList.Add(widthParameter, OleDbType.Deciaml).Value = WITestData.WIData[i].Width;
    parameterList.Add(angleParameter, OleDbType.Decimal).Value = WITestData.WIData[i].Width;
    parameterList.Add(commentParameter, OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = WITestData.WIData[i].Comment;
    counter++;
}
parameterList.Add("@reportNumber", OleDbType.Integer).Value = WITestData.ReportNumber;
```

Comment: I'm still not sure as to why i should use the oleDbtype when i was supposed to make the code sql adjusted, for using with sql server. All other methods are with sqlCommand/ Parameter and they work perfectly.
However I managed to solve the issue. If you'd like/ be interested in seeing the solution i can edit my question to showcase or just answer my own question. Thank you for the information though. I'm kind of new with this programming and language so im trying to learn.

Comment: If you connect to MS-Access you are unsing the OleDb client classes. If you connect to Sql Server you use the Sql Client classes. (unless you want to stick with OleDb and miss the benefits of the approriate Sql Server NET driver, named parameters for example). If you want to post your own answer to your problem you can. (Even accept it)

Answer (score 0):

This solved my question.

```
   int counter = 1;
        var parameterList = new List<SqlParameter>();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        string sqlCommand = $"UPDATE WITestData SET " +
            "Width01 = {widthParameter}, Angle01 = {angleParameter}, Comment01 = {commentParameter}, " +
            "Width02 = {widthParameter}, Angle02 = {angleParameter}, Comment02 = {commentParameter}, " +
            "Width03 = {widthParameter}, Angle03 = {angleParameter}, Comment03 = {commentParameter}, " +
            "Width04 = {widthParameter}, Angle04 = {angleParameter}, Comment04 = {commentParameter}, " +
            "Width05 = {widthParameter}, Angle05 = {angleParameter}, Comment05 = {commentParameter}, " +
            "Width06 = {widthParameter}, Angle06 = {angleParameter}, Comment06 = {commentParameter}, " +
            "Width07 = {widthParameter}, Angle07 = {angleParameter}, Comment07 = {commentParameter}, " +
            "Width08 = {widthParameter}, Angle08 = {angleParameter}, Comment08 = {commentParameter}, " +
            "Width09 = {widthParameter}, Angle09 = {angleParameter}, Comment09 = {commentParameter}, " +
            "Width10 = {widthParameter}, Angle10 = {angleParameter}, Comment10 = {commentParameter} " +
            "WHERE ReportNumber = @reportNumber";
        var parameters = new object[31];
        for (int i = 0; i < WITestData.WIData.Length; i++)
        {
            //input Parameters into sqlCommand
            string widthParameter = $"@width{(counter < 10 ? counter.ToString("D2") : counter.ToString() )}";
            string angleParameter = $"@angle{(counter < 10 ? counter.ToString("D2") : counter.ToString())}";
            string commentParameter = $"@comment{(counter < 10 ? counter.ToString("D2") : counter.ToString())}";
            using (command)
            {
                parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter(widthParameter, WITestData.WIData[i].Width));
                parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter(angleParameter, WITestData.WIData[i].Angle));
                parameterList.Add(new SqlParameter(commentParameter, WITestData.WIData[i].Comment));

                command.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            parameters[3 * i] = WITestData.WIData[i].Width;
            parameters[3 * i + 1] = WITestData.WIData[i].Angle;
            parameters[3 * i + 2] = WITestData.WIData[i].Comment;

            counter++;
        }
```

The code could probably look better but in that case I would attend to that at a later clean-up stage.